# Want to set a state object within a for loop: React+Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate

I have a state object which is basically an array of objects. I am doing a fetch call, and the array of objects returned by it should be set to the state object. But It I am unable to do the same.
Any alternative?
Where am I going wrong?

Help would be appreciated

```
 this.state = {
      accounts: [{firstname:"",lastname:"",age:"",id:""}],
 };

 async componentDidMount(){

   let useraccounts =  await this.fetchAccounts();
   if(useraccounts.length > 0)
     { 
       for(let i=0;i<useraccounts.length;i++)
        {
            account = {firstname:useraccounts[i].firstname,lastname:useraccounts[i].lastname,age:useraccounts[i].age,id:useraccounts[i].id}; 
            this.setState((prevState) => ({  accounts: [ ...prevState.accounts, account ]}));            
        }                   
     }  
 }

 fetchAccounts = async() => {

    //fetch API call which will return all users accounts

 }
```

Comment: prepare the array first in loop, then do setState only once. like this: `let arr = [];
for(let i=0;i<useraccounts.length;i++) {
  account = {
    firstname:useraccounts[i].firstname,
    lastname:useraccounts[i].lastname,
    age:useraccounts[i].age,id:useraccounts[i].id
  };
  arr.push(account);
}
this.setState((prevState) => ({  accounts: [ ...prevState.accounts, arr ]}));            `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `setState` for each account individually, just do a single call with all of the accounts:

```
async componentDidMount(){
  try {
    let useraccounts =  await this.fetchAccounts();
    let newAccounts = useraccounts.map(({firstname, lastname, age, id}) => ({firstname, lastname, age, id}));
    this.setState(({accounts}) => ({accounts: [...accounts, ...newAccounts]}));
  } catch (e) {
    // Do something with the error
  }
}
```

That gets the accounts, creates a new array with just the relevant properties (what you were doing in your `for` loop), then calls `setState` to add the new accounts.

Note that I'm doing destructuring in the parameter lists of the `map` callback and the `setState` callback to pick out only the parts of the objects they receive that I want. For instance, this:

```
let newAccounts = useraccounts.map(({firstname, lastname, age, id}) => ({firstname, lastname, age, id}));
```

is the same as this:

```
let newAccounts = useraccounts.map(account => {
  return {
    firstname: account.firstname,
    lastname: account.lastname,
    age: account.age,
    id: account.id
  };
});
```

It's just a bit more concise.

Of course, if you don't really need to copy the objects, you could just use the accounts you got from `fetchAccounts` directly:

```
async componentDidMount(){
  try {
    let useraccounts =  await this.fetchAccounts();
    this.setState(({accounts}) => ({accounts: [...accounts, ...useraccounts]}));
  } catch (e) {
    // Do something with the error
  }
}
```

---

Some notes on your original code:

- You're breaking one of the rules of promises by using an `async` function where nothing is going to handle the promise it returns: You need to handle any errors that occur, rather than ignoring them. That's why I added a `try`/`catch`.
- If you're doing `for(let i=0;i<useraccounts.length;i++)`, there's no need for `if(useraccounts.length > 0)` first. Your loop body won't run if there are no accounts.